# Actuators for gimbaling of engine in rockets and launch vehicles

Tags: spacex, merlin-1d, ssme, gimbaled-engines, rutherford-engine

For controlling the rockets to stay on course, continuous engine control is require which is done by using gimbal actuators.

What type of gimbal actuators have been used on [SSME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Main_Engine), [Rocketlab's Rutherford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_(rocket_engine)), [Spacex Merlin series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin_(rocket_engine_family)).

[image][image][image]

For Merlin-1D I have cheked [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23647/falcon-9-merlin-engine-thrust-vectoring) but the type of actuator is not mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

SSME & Merlin use hydraulic actuators. For instance,

> The engine is gimballed through two planes by hydraulic actuators for
>   vehicle pitch, yaw, and roll control. - [Space Transportation System, Space Shuttle Main Engine Orientation, pg 4 (PDF)](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2011/ph240/nguyen1/docs/SSME_PRESENTATION.pdf)

and

> Engine failure modes are minimized by eliminating separate subsystems
>   where appropriate. For example, the first-stage thrust vector control
>   system pulls from the high-pressure rocket-grade kerosene system,
>   rather than using a separate hydraulic fluid and pressurization
>   system. Using fuel as the hydraulic fluid eliminates potential
>   failures associated with a separate hydraulic system and with the
>   depletion of hydraulic fluid. - [Falcon 9 Users Guide, pg 8 (PDF)](https://www.spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/falcon_9_users_guide_rev_2.0.pdf)

The Rutherford engine is generally believed to use linear actuators as gimbal actuators, but I'm having difficulty finding an official source. I'll update if I locate that.

Comment: Looking forward for the reference of Rutherford engine. Linear actuator with what kind of motor (stepper, BLDC, servo)?

Comment: I wish I knew, I'll let you know if I do find it. I have found reference to 'brushless DC motors' in company literature, but I think that's specific to the pump motors. It does indicate company experience with BLDC at least.

Comment: You could link to [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21597/12102) for the Rutherford.