# New Glenn/Shepard gimbal engine actuators: hydraulic or electric?

Tags: blue-origin, gimbaled-engines, new-shepard, new-glenn

Falcon 9 uses hydraulic cylinders with RP-1 fuel as the hydraulic fluid to actuate the engine gimbals. They do this for stage 1 and stage 2, both of which use RP-1 for fuel.

But New Glenn uses methane for stage 1 and liquid hydrogen for stage 2. New Shepard uses liquid hydrogen exclusively. So I’m wondering if either of these fuels would make a suitable hydraulic fluid, and whether Blue Origin might have chosen electrical gimbal actuators instead (like I believe Elektron has)?

Comment: [Electron does indeed seem to use electric motors for gimbaling](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21597/12102). First stage has 2 x 9 = 18 linear electric actuators of some kind, and in 2018 at least they were blue!

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

According to a parts supplier, New Shepard uses a hydraulic system.

> JASC designed and manufactured the Flight Control System Actuators and the engine Thrust Vector Control Actuators used on New Shepard. Both of these actuators are servo-hydraulic units, with the former used to steer the vehicle and provide aerodynamic stability, and the latter to vector the engine/nozzle for the same purpose.

Source: JASC website post [New Shepard Space Vehicle Makes Fifth Flight](https://jasc-controls.com/new-shepard-space-vehicle-makes-fifth-flight/)

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks! This is super helpful. So hydraulics both for the engine gimbal actuators *and* the steering fins---and probably also for the drag fins, I would imagine.

Comment: And in fact, the JASC website you linked to shows a picture of an actuator that is practically identical to the ones I've seen in pictures of Falcon 9 engine gimbal actuators. I wouldn't be surprised if SpaceX and Blue Origin were both using JASC as their hydraulic actuator supplier.